# Why is my page directing back to the login page when I press enter to add a comment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created an Instagram clone and all of my functionality (Like photos, add comments) is working fine when in jsbin: http://jsbin.com/tecaha/edit?js,output

For example, when I type a comment and press enter, the comment is added. However, when I copy this code into Atom and upload to my server, or use my local environment, when I press enter the page just loops back to the login.

Can someone tell me what is wrong here?

Here is the link to the page on the server http://jshuadvd.com/instagram/feed.html

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
  <body>

    <header>
      <div class="top">        
        <ul>
          <li><i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
          <li id="logo">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SmdPZ6T.png" />
          </li>
          <li id="profile-photo">
            <img src="https://scontent-sea1-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-19/10731946_1517235648523785_1216221661_a.jpg" />
            <p class="username">username</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div id="container">
      <main>
        <div id="feed-container">
            <ul id="images">





            </ul>
          </div>         
      </main>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  font-family: "proxima-nova", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: #3E6D93;
  height: 50px;
}
.top {
  background: #467ea6;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(0.01, #467ea6), to(#27608c));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#467ea6 1%, #27608c 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#467ea6 1%, #27608c 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#467ea6 1%, #27608c 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#467ea6 1%, #27608c 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#467ea6', endColorstr='#27608c', GradientType=0);
  width: 100%;
}
.top li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#home-button, .fa-home {
  float: left;
  background-color: #305F87;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 7px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 35px;
}
.fa-home {
  padding-left: 12px;
}
#logo img {
  float: right;
  width: 110px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  padding: 6px;
}
#profile-photo  {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #305F87;
  border-right: 1px solid #305F87;
  width: auto;
}
#profile-photo img  {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#profile-photo p {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 5px;

}
#feed-container {
  background-color: #DFDFDF;
  width: 650px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
#images {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
#images img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
}
.below-image {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 550px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.like {
  float: left;
}
.fa-heart {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.liked {
  color: #ff0000;
}
.image-info {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  width: 437px;
  height: 52px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.image-info p {
  color: #467ea6;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.more {
  float: right;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}
.more, .info {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
  padding: 0 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.comment-container {
  width: 550px;
  margin-bottom: 65px;  
}

.add-a-comment {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 550px;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.add-a-comment p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
.add-a-comment input[type=text] {
  width: 420px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #4f4f4f;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 0;
  bottom: 40px;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}
input, select, textarea{
  color: #f00;
}
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
.inserted {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.post-liked .fa-heart {
   color: #f00;
}
.comment-click {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #4f4f4f;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 0;
  bottom: 40px; 
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}
.comment-list {
  width: 400px;
  text-align: left;  
}
.comment-list li{
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: #4f4f4f;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.fixed-container {
  height: 250px;
  width: 530px;
  overflow: scroll; 
} 
.un {
  color: #467ea6;
}
```

**JavaScript / jQuery**

```
// Variable of html strings

var bottom = '<div class="below-image">' +
    '<div class="like">' +
    '<i class="fa fa-heart fa-2x"></i>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="image-info">' +
    '<p>User Info</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="more">' +
    '<button class="info">···</button>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="clear"></div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="add-a-comment">' +

    '<div class="comment-container">' + 
    '<form class="comment" action="index.html" method="post">' +
    '<input id="enter" type="text" name="newcomment" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Add a comment...">' +
    '<button class="comment-click"></button>' +
    '</form>' +
    '<ul class="comment-list fixed-container">' +
    '</ul>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</li>' +
   '</div>' +
    '</div>';


// GET Request to grab the data from the JSON file
$(document).ready(function() {
  var jsonURL = "https://codesmith-precourse.firebaseio.com/instagram/-JqL35o8u6t3dTQaFXSV.json";
  var newImage = "http://yourbizrules.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Staying-Motivated.jpg";

  $.getJSON(jsonURL, function(json) {
    var imgList = "";

    $.each(json, function (i) {
        imgList += '<div class="post"><li><img class="inserted" src= " ' + json[i] + ' ">' + bottom;

    });


    $('#images').append(imgList);


// Like Photos
    $('#images').on('click', '.inserted', function() {
//  $('.fa-heart').toggleClass('liked');
      var post_block = $(this).parents('.post').first();
      post_block.toggleClass('post-liked');
    });

// Add Comment
    $('.comment-click').on('click', function() {
      var userName = "Username";
      //debugger;
      //console.log("username", userName, $(userName));

      var userComment = $(this).siblings('input[name=newcomment]').val();
        $(this).parent().siblings('.comment-list').append("<li>" + userName + ' ' + userComment + "</li>");

      $.each($('input'), function () {
    $(this).val("");

      });      
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: "loops back to login" so where is the server side code in the post?

Comment: There is no server side code. Everything is HTML, CSS & JavaScript / jQuery. I just added it to my server for you guys to be able to debug with the DevTools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that the form gets submitted when the user presses the enter key, so how to fix that is to hook the `onSubmit` event of the form.

To make this work, you need to apply these two changes:

**1. convert your button to a submit button so that clicking the button will submit the form**

`<button class="comment-click" type="submit"></button>`

**2. Hook the on submit event, which will be called either when the user presses enter or the user clicks the submit button**:

```
$('form.comment').on('submit', function(evt) {
    var userName = "Username";

    // note: "this" references the <form> element!
    var userComment = $(this).find('input[name=newcomment]').val();
    $(this).siblings('.comment-list').append("<li>" + userName + ' ' + userComment + "</li>");
    $(this).find('input[name=newcomment]').val("");

    // prevents the standard behaviour
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

**3. remove your old code i.e the `$('.comment-click').on('click', function() { ...`**

Also you should escape the user's input to prevent HTML/JS injection:

```
$(this).siblings('.comment-list').append($("<li></li>").text(userName + ' ' + userComment));
```

You can try this by entering something like `<h1>big!` on your current implementation.

Comment: When I do this, my page breaks. I followed the instructions specifically.

Comment: it should not, see the JS bin: http://jsbin.com/qetuyemude/2/edit?js,output if it breaks could you tell me what exactly breaks?

Comment: This works properly, I checked my code and yours. I added the `type="submit"`  to my button, but it isn't here on yours. Maybe that was the issue?

Comment: Thank you for your help BTW. I did not mention that!

Comment: whoops, it actually does work with the `type="submit"` too, see here http://jsbin.com/gesukejadi/1/edit?js,output

Comment: I see that, Hmmm. Very strange. Maybe I had a typo or something! THakn you again! One last question, any advice on how to target `userName` variable and `addClass()` of `.un` to it since it is a variable?

Comment: could you rephrase that? I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91326/discussion-between-jshuadvd-and-sled).

Answer (score 1):

because your comment form's action points to index.html

your index.html asks for login: http://jshuadvd.com/instagram/index.html

```
<form class="comment" action="index.html" method="post">
---
---
---
</form>
```

Comment: Ahhh! What should I change that to so that it would enter said comment?

Comment: do you need to comment on the original instagram item or you need the comment to be stored in your own database?

Comment: I need to comment on the instagram item. No database here. Essentially how I currently have it set up is that it just appends the text to a `<li>` in a `<ul>`